# Particles not spreading evenly over surface, they are clustered at two points (Donut tutorial)

Tags: particles, outliner

Overview in viewport: https://i.imgur.com/cQ0tnkt.png

Top part of Particles properties: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwZNX.png

Outliner overview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzW7x.png

Look at the short sprinkles. They are clustered on the left side and right side of the donut. Maybe something with the Count settings? Not too sure.

Blender 2.92.0

Part 2 level 2 of the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZ5ungDgFNc

Comment: Have you tried changing the seed? I'm not sure if this applies to your problem, but it might help.

Comment: I did try that and that does not work, only changes the location of the clusters. I will try remaking the weighted heat map. If it works I will report back with results.

Comment: maybe you've used a vertex group? please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/5fb7d297c915425c8999455486e588ce

Thank you for your time! I still haven't tried changing the heat map, currently editing the displacement bumps :)

Comment: Changing the heat map does not seem to work: https://i.imgur.com/SKxdNXC.png And here is full particle settings: https://i.imgur.com/UJLauO2.png and this one https://i.imgur.com/lACPBMD.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh gosh I think I solved it I ticked "Pick Random" under the Collection setting in Particle properties! [image: random] Looking at Andrew's tutorial he hasn't got it ticked and you can kinda tell he has the same issue it just isn't very noticeable on his donut.